# How to un-mark a SATA HDD “as spare” in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sata, configure, local-storage

I have a desktop computer with an extra HDD connected to it via SATA port, and I have done "mark as spare" to the drive, but I don't remember where I got to that setting, and I want to undo it. The HDD is no longer visible in Windows Explorer or Partition Manager. IDK what I did... It may have even been in BIOS but I didn’t re-find it. It is definitely specific to the hard disk itself, however, since changing which port it is attached to does not make it visible again.

I want to revert this setting and take the HDD back to normal. The HDD is empty, so data is in little danger, but its good space that I want to use. What do I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure how I did this, but thankfully I was able to undo it by live booting Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, and using Gparted to re-create the partition table. TYL!